# Serial communication from vb code to python and issues

Tags: python, vb.net, serial-port, communication

i cannot get a response from my device connected with serial rs232 in python or anywhere

i have a vb code on ms access that communicates but cannot recreate it in python the vb code sends this string to the device and takes response

I have tried with several combination to write to port but i get no answer
    ser.write("A")

with encode or with sending the 02 ASCII and the 03 after doesnt work

the vb code

```
MSCOMM.output = Chr(2)
MSCOMM.output = "A"
MSCOMM.output = Chr(3)
```

and the python code

```
import serial
from time import sleep    

ser = serial.Serial("COM2", 9600, timeout =5)

ser.write(0x02)
ser.write(0x65)
ser.write(0x03)
sleep(0.5)
x = ser.readline()
print(x)
```

i should get a value like b'0001280 kg \r \n' and i only get b''

Comment: Can you explain what is your device and how are you connecting it to your PC (USB cable, native UART, TTL, 5V, 3.3 V)? Have you ever successfully received a response from the device? If so, how? Why do you have a half second delay before listening?

Comment: I did it by sending a chr(2) encoded to ascii then "A" encoded to ascii then close with a chr(3) and read just read just 20 chars from the serial port ..thanks for your comment !

Comment: If you did it successfully with a terminal maybe you need to have a very short delay between characters from some reason instead of after sending the three of them? Or maybe the issue is you cannot have such a long (0.5 s) delay to wait for the answer. If you have timeout=5 seconds you don't need to have the delay before reading (ser.readline() will wait for 5 seconds and read everything until it catches an end-of-line character)